# 1/4" water line through kitchen quartz countertop

Tags: hole, quartz

I want to run a 1/4" water line from the cold water line underneath the kitchen countertop to the water reservoir on my coffee maker. What size hole should I drill and what do I use to drill it? After I have the hole drilled, what kind of grommet do I need to make up the difference between the hole size and the 1/4" water line?

Comment: Is the result going to typically be hidden behind the machine? If so, the hole should be minimized and I don't think I'd even use a grommet. It just requires a larger hole. If you need to prevent spill drainage, silicone it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The coffee maker sits on the kitchen island and the material that acts as a backsplash is the same as the countertop so there is no advantage in coming through the back. I wanted to make the whole setup such that if the next owners didn't want to use the water feed it would be easy for them to use some nice looking cap to cover the hole.

Comment: Is there a sink in the island?

Answer (score 2):

1/4" **nominal** PEX would be a 3/8 or 7/16" hole, with a 3/8" outside diameter.

1/4" **outside** diameter tubing would be 1/4-5/16" (or 6.5-7mm)

**Diamond core drills** are the usual method for drilling stone or stone-adjacent countertops.

**Might** be simpler to run it in the wall, behind the countertop; rather than through a stone-adjacent countertop.

Comment: pex isn't rated for long term uv exposure